# using output of scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline later in python or in Matlab without needing original datapoints

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, spline

I'm using [`scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) to smoothly interpolate a large amount of data. Works great. I get an object which acts like a function.

Now I want to save the spline points for later and use them in Matlab (and also Python, but that's less urgent), without needing the original data. How can I do this?

In scipy I have no clue; UnivariateSpline does not seem to offer a constructor with the previously-computed knots and coefficients.

In MATLAB, I've tried the Matlab functions [`spline()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) and `pchip()`, and while both come close, they have errors near the endpoints that look kind of like [Gibbs ears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Here is a sample set of data that I have, in Matlab format:

```
splinedata = struct('coeffs',[-0.0412739180955273 -0.0236463479425733 0.42393753107602 -1.27274336116436 0.255711720888164 1.93923263846732 -2.30438927604816 1.02078680231079 0.997156858475075 -2.35321792387215 0.667027554745454 0.777918416623834],...
 'knots',[0 0.125 0.1875 0.25 0.375 0.5 0.625 0.75 0.875 0.9999],...
 'y',[-0.0412739180955273 -0.191354308450615 -0.869601364377744 -0.141538578624065 0.895258135865578 -1.04292294390242 0.462652465278345 0.442550440125204 -1.03967756446455 0.777918416623834])
```

The coefficients and knots are the result of calling `get_coeffs()` and `get_knots()` on the scipy UnivariateSpline. The 'y' values are the values of the UnivariateSpline at the knots, or more precisely:

```
 y = f(f.get_knots())
```

where f is my UnivariateSpline.

How can I use this data to make a spline that matches the behavior of the UnivariateSpline, without having to use the Curve-Fitting Toolbox? I don't need to do any data fitting in Matlab, I just need to know how to construct a cubic spline from knots/coefficients/spline values.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but a `UnivariateSpline` object at least seems to be pickleable, in case you wanted to re-use your fit in Python.

Comment: A detailed answer to the OP's question is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488637/getting-spline-equation-from-univariatespline-object/25330648#25330648. This answer provides a means of manually evaluating the spline knots and coefficients, so that the OP can try to match them up to the inputs used by other programs.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using the functions `_eval_args()` and `_from_tck()` from the class `UnivariateSpline`. The first one gives returns the spline parameters, which you can store and later create a similar spline object using the the second one.

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
y = np.exp(-x**2) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(50)

spl1 = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=.5)

xi = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)

tck = spl1._eval_args

spl2 = UnivariateSpline._from_tck(tck)

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5, label='data')
plt.plot(xi, spl1(xi), 'b', label='original spline')
plt.plot(xi, spl2(xi), 'y:', lw=4, label='recovered spline')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In scipy, try [scipy.interpolate.splev](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html), which takes

> tck: a sequence ... containing the knots, coefficients, and degree of the spline.

Added: the following python class creates spline functions:
init with (knots, coefs, degree),
then use it just like spline functions created by `UnivariateSpline( x, y, s )`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import splev
    # http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html

class Splinefunc:
    """ splinef = Splinefunc( knots, coefs, degree )
        ...
        y = splinef( x )  # __call__

        19june untested
    """

    def __init__( self, knots, coefs, degree ):
        self.knots = knots
        self.coefs = coefs
        self.degree = degree

    def __call__( self, x ):
        return splev( x, (self.knots, self.coefs, self.degree ))
```

Comment: no, that just allows me to evaluate a spline, it doesn't let me recreate a UnivariateSpline object.