# Writing B-spline as Piecewise Cubic

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression, spline

I'm using Scipy's SmoothBivariateSpline class to create a cubic B-spline on bivariate data. I now need to write the piecewise polynomial expression for this spline curve.

My mathematical background isn't very strong, so I wasn't able to write my own algorithm for transforming from the t, c, k output of the SmoothBivariateSpline to a polynomial representation. If this is feasible, can you provide pointers on how to approach this? I noticed that Scipy has interpolate.ppform, but I can't find any docs for it - is this relevant?

One method I was considering was breaking down the domain of the spline into regions at each knot (with `(n-1)^2` total regions, where `n` is the number of knots), then performing a cubic regression on many points on the spline curve in each region in order to calculate a cubic regression to the data for every region. Is this a valid approach?

The former method seems much more rigorous, so I'd prefer to use that one, but the latter is also acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

B-splines can be converted to piecewise polynomials efficiently.

This can be easily done in Scipy 0.14.0 (to be released in a couple of months) which has `scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline`.

The algorithm of computing piecewise polynomials from the spline `t, c, k` itself is very simple, so in the meantime you can write your own function that computes the polynomial coefficients:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L938

Comment: OK, I'll write my own function for this task. It looks like from_spline simply finds the Taylor polynomial, centered at a knot. In   my case, since I have a bivariate spline, would I calculate the two-dimensional Taylor function instead? Also, what would be the breakpoints?

Comment: @Draksis: a detailed answer to a similar question is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488637/getting-spline-equation-from-univariatespline-object/25330648#25330648. The answer provides a function for manually evaluating the 1D B-spline knots and coefficients, giving some insight into what they mean. Perhaps you can generate something similar by expanding on the 1D case provided.