# How to obtain perfect fit from np.random.power function

Tags: python, optimization

I have generated random data using:

```
bkg= 240-140*np.random.power(3.5,50000)
```

I plotted the points into a histogram by using

```
h_all = plt.hist(all,bins=binedges,histtype='step')
```

My question is, provided that I know the pdf (in this case called "bkg") can I generate a curve using `scipy.optimize` that fits the points generated perfectly, and what equation it is for the curve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remark that your `bkg` is NOT a probability density function (pdf). Rather, it is a list of *observations* from a pdf. By calling `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` on this list of observations, you get to see a curve that approximates the (offset and scaled version of the) probability density function. If you are given this curve, it is possible to get a good estimation of the parameters needed to model this, provided you've been given the parameterized model a priori.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

offset, scale, a, nsamples = 240, -140, 3.5, 500000
bkg = offset + scale*np.random.power(a, nsamples)  # values range between (offset, offset+scale), which map to 0 and 1
nbins = 100

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(bkg, bins=nbins, histtype='stepfilled', edgecolor='none')
```

[image: reversed probability density function of the power function distribution]

If now you are given the centers of these bins and the counts,

```
xdata = .5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
ydata = count
```

and you are asked to find the parameters of the power distribution function that fits to this data (-> someone told you this, you trust that source), then you could go about in the following manner.

First, observe that the power distribution function `P(x,a)` is a monotonously increasing function (i.e. `P(x1, a ) < P(x2, a)` when `0 <= x1 < x2 <= 1`). That means that the dataset given above has been flipped left-to-right, or that it represents `factor*P(x, a )` with `factor < 0`.

Next, notice that the given data is not given over the interval `[0,1]`, typical for a probability density function. That means that you should rescale the given `xdata` to the `[0,1]` interval prior to attempting to fit the power function distribution to it. Just by observing the graph, you figure out that the values that 0 and 1 map to are 100 and 240. However, this is just luck here, because matplotlib chose a sensible range for plotting. When you are confronted with not actually knowing the limits to which 0 and 1 have mapped to, you could choose the less optimal (but still very good) choice of `xdata[0] - binwidth/2` and `xdata[-1] + binwidth/2` or (a slightly worse choice) `xdata[0]` and `xdata[-1]`. From the previous paragraph, you know that 1 maps to  `xdata[0] - binwidth/2 :=: a` and 0 maps to `xdata[-1] + binwidth/2 :=: b`. The linear map that does this is `lambda x: (a - b)*x + b` (simple algebra).

If you pass this to [0,1]-mapped version of the xdata to `curve_fit`, it'll give you a good guess for the exponent.

```
def get_model(nobservations, binwidth, scale, offset):
    def model(bin_centers, exponent):
        x = (bin_centers - offset)/scale
        y = exponent*x**(exponent - 1)
        normed_y = nobservations * binwidth * y / np.abs(scale)
        return normed_y
    return model

binwidth = np.diff(xdata)[0]
p0, _ = curve_fit(get_model(nsamples, binwidth, scale=-xdata.ptp() - binwidth, offset=xdata[-1] + binwidth/2), xdata, ydata)
print(p0)  # prints e.g.: 3.37117679

plt.plot(xdata, get_model(nsamples, binwidth, scale=-xdata.ptp() - binwidth, offset=xdata[-1] + binwidth/2)(xdata, *p0))
```

At this moment, you have found a rather accurate description of the distribution
that was used to generate the observations of `bkg`:

```
f(x) = offset + scale*(exponent * x**(exponent - 1))
     = (xdata[-1] + binwidth/2) + (-xdata.ptp() - binwidth)*(p0[0] * x**(p0[0] - 1))
     ~ 234.85 - 1.34.85*(3.37 * x**(3.37 - 1))
```

By the way, I'd like to point out that replicating `bkg` (the observations from the distribution)
as a perfect copy is something you can only do if you know the exact parameters of the distribution (240, -140 and 3.5) AND set the seed for the random number generation equal to the seed that was in effect prior to the initial call to `np.random.power`.

[image: fit to reversed probability density function of the power function distribution]

If you'd like to fit a curve to the histogram using [splines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline), you should retrieve the knots and coefficients from the generated spline and pass those into the function of `bspleval`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488637/getting-spline-equation-from-univariatespline-object). The topic of writing out those equations is a long one however, and there are numerous resources on the internet that you can check to understand how it's done. Needless to say, that function `bspleval` is what you'll need in case you want to go that route. If it were me, I'd go the route of curve fitting shown above.

Comment: I managed to generate a interpolated curve using spline. But I could not find the specification to get a simple spline function back. Also could you specify in this case how the offset power distribution should look like? I have tried using (1-x)**2.5 but that didnt work.

Comment: @JamesJ, I've elaborated the approach of curve fitting using an offset and scaled distribution. I hope it's much clearer now.